# Is there some way to don't show the component name on the html in Angular 2 or superior?

Tags: angular, angular-components

This component...

```
<my-component>
   <p>Hello !</p>
</my-component>
```

...Inside the html template....

```
<div class="myClass">
   <my-component></mycomponent>
</div>
```

...Will render something like this on the client side:

```
<div class="myClass">
   <my-component>
     <p>Hello !</b>
  </mycomponent>
</div>
```

Is there some how to not display the component html tag , but display the components inner content ? Something like...

```
<div class="myClass">
      <p>Hello !</b>
</div>
```

Comment: did you get any answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a selector, you could try to do

```
<div class="myClass">
   <div my-component></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, according to [this page](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xvBZoFuNq9hsgRhPPZOJC-Z48AHEbIBPlOCBTSD8m0Y/edit)

> Directives that replace their host element (replace: true directives in Angular 1) are not supported in Angular 2. In many cases these directives can be upgraded over to regular component directives.

Comment: It's not about migration strategy, sorry.

Comment: I am using  a framework that's probably using a pseudo-class first-child...and this is causing unexpected behaviour because the first-child will be the component selector tag inside the html :(

Comment: I know it's not about migration, I'm just telling you that **unlike AngularJS**, Angular doesn't allow tag replacement. I see your issue, could you give more information about that in your post, so that we focus on how to correct it instead of how to change Angular ? :)